# How to edit mvc list using viewmodel

Tags: c#

I want to write edit code using viewmodel but I'm completely puzzled.

here is my viewmodel

```
    public SearchCustomersCriteria SearchCustomersCriteria { get; set; }
    public SearchCustomersResults SearchCustomersResults { get; set; }

    public SearchProductsCriteria SearchProductsCriteria { get; set; }
    public SearchProductsResults SearchProductsResults { get; set; }

    public List<SelectedProduct> ListOfSelectedProducts { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public decimal Deposit { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    //public string Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    //public SelectedProduct SelectedProduct { get; set; } 
    public BentleyBeds.InternalManagement.Web.Utility.Helper.OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

}
#endregion

#region Selected products
public class SelectedProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
#endregion

#region Customer search

public class SearchCustomersCriteria
{
    public string FristName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class SearchCustomersResults
{
    public List<Data.Customer> ListOfCustomers { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCustomerId { get; set; }
}

#endregion 

#region Products
public class SearchProductsCriteria
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class SearchProductsResults
{
    public List<Data.Product> ListOfProducts { get; set; }
    public int SelectedProductId { get; set; }
}

}
```

This is controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new CreateOrderViewModel();
        //model.ListOfSelectedProducts = new List<SelectedProduct>(){
        //    new SelectedProduct(){Description="ab", ProductName ="abc", Quantity=0, UnitPrice=0}};
        model.ListOfSelectedProducts = new List<SelectedProduct>();
        model.SearchCustomersCriteria = new SearchCustomersCriteria();
        model.SearchCustomersResults = new SearchCustomersResults();
        model.SearchProductsCriteria = new SearchProductsCriteria();
        model.SearchProductsResults = new SearchProductsResults();

        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateOrderViewModel model, List<string> ProductName, List<SetupProductViewModel> productViewModel, string FristName)
    {

        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
            try
            {

                var status = model.Status.ToString();
                var deliver = model.DeliveryDate;
                using (var ctx = new BentleyBedsEntities())
                {
                    //add into orders
                    var order = new Order()
                    {
                        CustomerId = model.SearchCustomersResults.SelectedCustomerId,
                        DeliveryDate = model.DeliveryDate,
                        Deposit = model.Deposit,
                        StatusId = helper.GetEnumKey(status),
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now

                    };
                    ctx.Orders.Add(order);
                    //var result = ctx.SaveChanges();

                    var id = order.OrderId;
                    if (ctx.Orders.Any(e => e.OrderId == id))
                    {
                        ctx.Orders.Attach(order);
                        //tx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myEntity, EntityState.Modified);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctx.Orders.Add(order);
                    }

                    var result = ctx.SaveChanges();


                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        var orderId = order.OrderId;
                        foreach (SelectedProduct selectedProduct in model.ListOfSelectedProducts)
                        {
                            if (!selectedProduct.Deleted)
                            {
                                var orderDetails = new OrdersDetail()
                                {
                                    OrderId = orderId,
                                    ProductId = selectedProduct.ProductId,
                                    Price = selectedProduct.UnitPrice,
                                    Quantity = selectedProduct.Quantity,
                                    Description = selectedProduct.Description
                                };
                                ctx.OrdersDetails.Add(orderDetails);
                                var results = ctx.SaveChanges();
                            }


                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                UpdateException updateException = (UpdateException)ex.InnerException;
                SqlException sqlException = (SqlException)updateException.InnerException;

                foreach (SqlError error in sqlException.Errors)
                {
                    // TODO: Do something with your errors
                    var result = error.Message;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var stat = ex.ToString();
                return View("Create", model);
                //throw;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //}
        //return View("Create", model);

    }

    // GET: /CreateOrder/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Order order = context.Orders.Find(id);
        if (order == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(context.Customers, "Firstname", "Firstname", order.Customer.Firstname);
        return View(order);
    }

    // POST: /CreateOrder/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "OrderId,CustomerId,Customer,Firstname,Deposit,DeliveryDate,StatusId,CreatedBy,CreatedOn,CompanyID")] Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(context.Customers, "Firstname", "Firstname", order.Customer.Firstname);
        return View(order);
    }
```

How should I write edit code in controller and view?

Comment: what is wrong with current code?

Comment: i want to write edit code using the view model, the written edit code is generated using model binding

Comment: What's wrong with the generated code?

Comment: You can submit your form to Edit action which is decorated with HttpPost annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can create your edit code using a ViewModel. First of all, create the class for the ViewModel based on the specific items in the Model you want to edit.

For example, let's say you have a Book class:

```
public class Book
{
   public int BookID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int LibraryID { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you want a ViewModel to edit only the Name of the book. Then, it would look like this:

```
public class EditBookViewModel
{
   public int BookID { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In your Controller, you would have a method 'Get' that returns the data, and a 'Post' method that puts the data back in the database. It would look like this:

```
public class YourController
{
   ...
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
   {
      Book book = ctx.Books.Find(id);
      var viewModel = new EditBookViewModel()
      {
         BookID = book.BookID,
         Name = book.Name
      }
      return View(viewModel);
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Edit(EditBookViewModel viewModel)
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         var model = ctx.Books.Find(model.BookID);
         viewModel.Name = model.Name;
         ctx.SaveChanges();
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   ...
}
```

Make sure you view is prepared to receive the EditBookViewModel. You can do that by adding at the top of the view:

```
@model EditBookViewModel
```

Comment: Yeah, no problem! :)
If you could please mark the answer as accepted, just click the check mark outline to the left of the answer